# How to dinamically change document text on a VSCode Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, plugins, vscode-extensions

I am currently working on a vscode extension, built with typescript, but I'm having some problems with TextEdit as there is little to no information online. What I want to do is the following:

If a user types `1` I want it to be changed to `<int>` (this is just an example). This change should be checked whenever a user inputs any character into the text document. To do this, I am using `connection.onDidChangeContent()` and trying to return a TextEdit[], but nothing changes in the user's text document. If I use `connection.onDocumentFormatting()`, I am able to return a TextEdit[] that successfully changes the user's document. How can I accomplish this with the `OnDidChangeContent()` function? Is it possible to do so?

Thank you

Comment: Where in the VSC API docs have you find these 2 `on????()` functions. I did a page search and could not find them

Comment: Mainly messing around with the extension. ```connection``` is a created IConnection, and I found those functions with the autocomplete after typing in ```.```

Comment: Where is the docs of `IConnection`? VSC is not dot-net but JavaScript

Comment: It is a class that extends from the ```Connection``` interface. All this is found in the vscode-languageserver node module. Should probably also mention that the extension that i'm working on is being made using the Language Server Protocol